# is this code is valid to search element in singly linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
int search( struct node **front, int val)
{
   struct node *cur;
     cur=*front;
   while(cur!=NULL)
   {
       cur=cur->next;
   }
   return  cur!=NULL;
}
```

Comment: It seems you're missing the logic for checking if the current node contains the wanted value (int val) and breaks the loop, but otherwise it would seem like that should iterate through the list without problem (not knowing how your node-struct looks like makes it pretty hard to say anything for certain).

Comment: What's the use of `val` as the argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will always run to the end of the list, then return `0`, so no. You need to compare with `val` somewhere.

Also, passing `front` as a `struct node **` is not necessary, since you're never assigning `*front`. Pass it as a `const struct node *` instead.

Your code is equivalent to

```
int search(struct node **front, int val)
{
    return 0;
}
```

except that it will crash and burn if it is passed a `NULL` first argument.

Answer (score 1):

No. Nowhere in your logic you are making use of `val`. Try this -

```
int search( struct node *front, int val)
{
   while(front != NULL)
   {
        if( front->val == val ) // Assuming struct node has val member which you are trying to compare to
           return 1;  // found it

        front=front->next;
   }
   return 0;  // Not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the comparison to the variable val being made ?
The code can not check whether a node with value "val" is present in the linked list.